# What is the purpose of the sub-interpreter API in CPython?

Tags: mod-wsgi, python

I'm unclear on why the sub-interpreter API exists and why it's used in modules such as the mod_wsgi apache module.  Is it mainly used for creating a security sandbox for different applications running within the same process, or is it a way to allow concurrency with multiple threads?  Maybe both? Are there other purposes?

Answer (score 13):

I imagine the purpose is to create separate python execution environments. For instance, [mod_wsgi](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) (Apache Python module) hosts a single python interpreter and then hosts multiple applications within sub-interpreters (in the default configuration).

Some key points from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#Py_NewInterpreter):

- This is an (almost) totally separate environment for the execution of Python code. In particular, the new interpreter has separate, independent versions of all imported modules, including the fundamental modules `__builtin__`, `__main__` and `sys`.
- The table of loaded modules (sys.modules) and the module search path (sys.path) are also separate.
- Because sub-interpreters (and the main interpreter) are part of the same process, the insulation between them isn’t perfect — for example, using low-level file operations like os.close() they can (accidentally or maliciously) affect each other’s open files.
- Because of the way extensions are shared between (sub-)interpreters, some extensions may not work properly; this is especially likely when the extension makes use of (static) global variables, or when the extension manipulates its module’s dictionary after its initialization.

Comment: Does this mean that different interpreters can run concurrently in different threads?  I'm still unclear on whether or not different interpreters in the same process share the same GIL.

Comment: The GIL is a global object for the process, and is shared among the sub-interpreters. So no, they cannot run concurrently. http://objectmix.com/python/377035-multiple-independent-python-interpreters-c-c-program.html

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I've been trying to figure out whether there's any way around the threading limitations of python and the GIL, and I'm not coming up with anything.

Comment: The GIL only comes into play for execution of actual Python code. So, if you are using C extension modules which are able to do work without holding the GIL, you can still get some measure of concurrency. Some C extension modules deliberately partition their data so they can do this and thus get benefits of multi cpu/core systems.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, I imagine that can also cause trouble if the modules unknowingly share states?

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant Does indeed occur. The psycopg2 was broken there for a while from memory as didn't partition data for different sub interpreters properly. Thus could only be used in one sub interpreter at a time.

Comment: I believe the stdlib json module also has issues (at least it did some versions back). I experienced some weird issues that went away when I disabled sub-interpreter use in mod_wsgi.

Comment: Is any of this unsafe with database operations?  Is it better to use fastcgi?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood it last, the idea was to be able to execute multiple applications as well as *multiple copies of the same application* within the same process.

This is a feature found in other scripting languages (e.g. TCL), and is of particular use to gui builders, web servers, etc.

It breaks in python because many extensions are not multiple-interpreter safe, so one interpreter's actions could affect the variables in another interpreter.